# How to programmatically overlay a shader on a terrain by mask (Unity)?

Tags: unity, shaders, terrain, masking

I can paint the terrain with textures.I would like to see water drawn with a shader, and not a stationary water texture on the terrain. Moreover, it was possible to assign a shader to the terrain, but the problem is that in this case the shader is superimposed on the entire terrain tile.

How to write a code that would apply a shader to a terrain using a mask?

Comment: It's probably going to look a lot better if you just lower the terrain where you want to put the water, and then add a flat plane with your water shader.

Comment: @Kevin my supervisor is against it. A bunch of other problems arise. For example, removing a camera leads to a change in terrain

Comment: What do you mean by "removing a camera leads to a change in terrain"? The terrain is dynamically modified when cameras are removed? Why?

Comment: @Kevin  yes, the program changes the landscape and replaces high polygonal objects.Your option will not work for me

Comment: @Kevin What for? Save resources. Large map

Comment: Unity's built-in Terrain already includes LOD support to reduce complexity at greater distances. I'm not sure whether this is what you're referring to. It's not going to deform the terrain so much that your water-filled areas no longer display correctly if you use the method I describe.

However, if your water is painted onto the terrain, it's going to _look like_ it's painted on the terrain; it won't be flat (especially if the terrain topography changes significantly when you move the camera) and there won't be a natural looking edge where the terrain would normally drop into the water.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110965/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-kevin).

Comment: @Kevin I am not deciding how to do this. I need to repeat what is written in the question